# How can Raman Spectra be utilised to know the crystal structure?

Tags: crystals, x-ray-crystallography, raman-spectroscopy

If Raman spectroscopy is using a visible or infrared source to excite phonons in the crystal, that is much different from XRD which is using higher energy X-rays scattered from the crystal planes. How can we use Raman spectroscopy to know the crytsal structure? Do you know and example? Any simple reference with excercises.

Comment: Why not to type Raman + Crystallography in a search bar first? https://www.spectroscopyonline.com/view/raman-crystallography and https://www.lbt-scientific.com/uploads/6/0/1/3/60131373/raman_crystallography.pdf, for instance

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But i have already downloaded and read this paper before I asked the question.